# Group by % to calculate weight of a non numerical column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df below as:

```
 day   | mealtype
Monday   Snack
Monday   Snack
Monday   Dinner
Tuesday  Breakfast
Monday   Dinner
Tuesday  Dinner
Sunday   Snack
Sunday   Dinner
Sunday   Lunch
```

I want to calculate the % of times a meal type occurs each day

I have previous code below that gives me the calculation of a similar calculation I previously coded, but it calculated the sum in the group by of an amount column.

```
 cols = ['day', 'mealtype']
    cols2 = ['day']
    
    (df.groupby(cols).amount.apply(lambda x: x.sum())/
     df.groupby(cols2).amount.apply(lambda x: x.sum()))
```

Here I dont have an amount, I simply want to just calculate % that each type of meal occurs in each day.

expected output:

```
Monday Snacks .5
Monday Dinner .5
Tuesday Breakfast .5
Tuesday Dinner .5
Sunday  Snack .33
Sunday  Lunch .33
Sunday  Dinner .33
```

Thanks!

Comment: I added manual sample output just for reference, Monday contains 2 dinners and 2 snacks so its half for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please `groupby(),value_counts(normalize)`,and name output `%`

```
 df.groupby('day')['mealtype'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame('%').reset_index().round(1)


    day    mealtype    %
0   Monday     Dinner  0.5
1   Monday      Snack  0.5
2   Sunday     Dinner  0.3
3   Sunday      Lunch  0.3
4   Sunday      Snack  0.3
5  Tuesday  Breakfast  0.5
6  Tuesday     Dinner  0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way with `groupby` :

```
df = df.groupby('day')['mealtype'].value_counts().div(df.groupby('day')['mealtype'].count())
df = df.to_frame('percent').reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       day   mealtype   percent
0   Monday     Dinner  0.500000
1   Monday      Snack  0.500000
2   Sunday     Dinner  0.333333
3   Sunday      Lunch  0.333333
4   Sunday      Snack  0.333333
5  Tuesday  Breakfast  0.500000
6  Tuesday     Dinner  0.500000
```